# How to join nodes when editing a boundary?

Tags: qgis, editing

Using QGIS 2.8.2, I have the following layer:

[image]

I'd like to remove the white strip and have each end closed off. Looking more closely, I need to join the nodes at each end as shown in red pen, such that the white area is now shaded yellow like the rest:

[image]

I am at a total loss on this one. I've tried the various geometry tools, but nothing seems to work. I think this should be easily done?

Comment: Did you try the node tool to move the nodes together?

Comment: Yes, but the nodes don't join/merge. In doing that, it ultimately just shrinks the width of the white strip, but still leaves two lines across.

Comment: @underdark, to be more specific, I want to merge the two circled nodes and remove the connection to the node(s) at the other end.

Comment: So you want to merge the polygons? Or is it actually the same polygon?

Comment: @underdark, it's the same polygon. For context, the white space is water that joins two lakes, making the rest land. I'm trying to delete the river

Comment: It might help if you add a picture zoomed to the whole polygon.

Comment: Have you tried to digitize a patch overlapping the white strip, and merged it with the polygon? Be sure to take the attributes from the polygon.

Comment: @Detlev, I have not. Do you have a link to more information on how to do that? I'm still quite new to QGIS. Thank you!

Comment: Set layer in edit mode and digitize a polygon such that the nodes you want to connect are snapped, and otherwise keep inside the big polygon. Like you would do, if you have to tape a real gap in some sheet of paper. Then use Edit -> Merge objects. For an example see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MT1ruGUXu8Y